# Dynamic background image on a TextView from a ListView/ row

Tags: android, background, textview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` that has two `TextViews`. I'm trying to dynamically set a background image to one of the `TextViews`.  I have about 18 different images that I want to display depending on the category of each item/row. The images are named `"abc1"`, `"abc2"`, etc.  Here is the code for my custom `CursorAdapter`:

```java
  private class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout , cursor, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        // Get the resource name and id
        String resourceName = "R.drawable.abc" + cursor.getString(7);
        int resid = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName,"drawable",context.getPackageName());

        // Create the idno textview with background image
        TextView idno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idno);
        idno.setText(cursor.getString(3));
        idno.setBackgroundResource(resid);

        // create the material textview
        TextView materials = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.materials);
        materials.setText(cursor.getString(1)); 
    }
}
```

When I run it in debug, `resid` always returns `0` which indicates the resource was not found. The `resourceName` looks correct, id: `"R.drawable.abc1"`.  I imported the image files into `res/drawable` folder and they are listed in `R.java`.

Is this the right way to go about this or does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the full name, for example `R.drawable.abc1`, you use only the name after `drawable`. It's the job of `getIdentifier()` to build up the correct `String` from the `name`, `type` and `package`. So, the use of `getIdentifier()` should be:

```
String resourceName = "abc" + cursor.getString(7);
int resid = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName,"drawable",context.getPackageName());
```

Also, you should look at another approach of setting the images as backgrounds, because the `getIdentifier()` is a much slower method to execute and it will be called in the `bindView` callback that could be called a lot of times as the user scrolls the `ListView` up and down(sometimes the user could do this at a very quick pace).

**EDIT :**

One way you can use the `getIdentifier` more efficiently is to initialize the ids in the custom `CursorAdapter` and store in a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` the mapping between the number that appears in the name(abc **1**, abc **2** etc) and the actual id:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> setUpIdsMap() {
     HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapIds = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
     // I don't know if you also have abc0, if not use this and substract 1 from the cursor value you get
     for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
         String resourceName = "abc" + 0;
         int resid =       context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName,"drawable",context.getPackageName());
         mapIds.put(i, resid);
     }
```

}

In the adapter's constructor:

```
//...field in your adapter class
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> ids = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

//in the constructor:
//...
    ids = setUpIdsMap();  
//...
```

Then in the `bindView` method use the array returned by:

```
//...
 // Create the idno textview with background image
        TextView idno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idno);
        idno.setText(cursor.getString(3));
        idno.setBackgroundResource(ids.get(cursor.getString(7)));//depending if you have abc0 or not you may want to substract 1 from cursor.getString(7) to match the value from the setUpIdsMap method
//...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I realized that the "R.drawable" was probably unnecessary since you have to pass which resource to get: "drawable". Makes perfect sense now!

Comment: I'll explore the hashmap, but I would have to manually initialize the map as the numbers are necessarily sequential. The category for each record could be 1 which is abc1 or it could be 1.1 which is abc11.
thanks again.